# Merging GRASS GIS calls in Linux bash terminal/scripts

Tags: linux, bash

I normally use bash scripts (ie. `#!/bin/bash`) to include different Linux-based tools (eg. `awk`, `sed`, `cut`), software (eg. `GMT`, `GDAL`, `SAGA`), and even languages (eg. `#!/usr/bin/env python`). However, so far I have not found any simple ways to add tools from the GRASS GIS software.

Could you please provide a simple example of how to do this?

In Linux I create a bash script in this way:

1. Open Linux terminal (eg. `Ctrl+Alt+T`)
2. Write: `vim myscript.bash`
3. Add: `#!/bin/bash -x`
4. Start adding code from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in Ubuntu 20.04:

```
export GISBASE=/lib/grass78/ 
export PATH=$PATH:$GISBASE/bin:$GISBASE/scripts
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$GISBASE/lib

if [ ! "$PYTHONPATH" ] ; then
   PYTHONPATH="$GISBASE/etc/python"
else
   PYTHONPATH="$GISBASE/etc/python:$PYTHONPATH"
fi
   export PYTHONPATH
   
export GIS_LOCK=$$
export GISRC=$HOME/.grassrc7+
export GISRC=/tmp/grass7-${USER}-$GIS_LOCK/gisrc
rm -fr /tmp/grass7-${USER}-$GIS_LOCK
mkdir /tmp/grass7-${USER}-$GIS_LOCK
export TMPDIR="/tmp/grass7-${USER}-$GIS_LOCK"
echo "GISDBASE: /home/guillermo" >>$GISRC
echo "LOCATION_NAME: waterkant" >>$GISRC
echo "MAPSET: PERMANENT" >>$GISRC
echo "GRASS_GUI: text" >>$GISRC

g.version
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you read the documentation on the GRASS Wiki page. There are several steps needed to set up the GRASS environment.  My answer will mostly be some copy/paste of [this page](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Shell) in order to avoid a "link only" answer.

```
    # Example in bash shell syntax:
 
   # path to GRASS binaries and libraries:
   export GISBASE=/usr/lib64/grass78
 
   export PATH=$PATH:$GISBASE/bin:$GISBASE/scripts
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$GISBASE/lib
   
   # set PYTHONPATH to include the GRASS Python lib
   if [ ! "$PYTHONPATH" ] ; then
      PYTHONPATH="$GISBASE/etc/python"
   else
      PYTHONPATH="$GISBASE/etc/python:$PYTHONPATH"
   fi
   export PYTHONPATH
 
   # use process ID (PID) as lock file number:
   export GIS_LOCK=$$
 
   # settings for graphical output to PNG file (optional)
   export GRASS_PNGFILE=/tmp/grass6output.png
   export GRASS_TRUECOLOR=TRUE
   export GRASS_WIDTH=900
   export GRASS_HEIGHT=1200
   export GRASS_PNG_COMPRESSION=1
   export GRASS_MESSAGE_FORMAT=plain
```

In addition, you must also define a grass session.

```
    # path to GRASS settings file
   export GISRC=$HOME/.grassrc7
```

Then you can start with some command lines (e.g. adding new column to mydata)

```
v.db.addcol mydata="new_col DOUBLE PRECISION"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `--exec` parameter of the *grass* executable ([link to documentation of grass executable](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/grass.html#batch-jobs-with-the-exec-interface)):

```bash
grass -c elevation.tiff -e /path/to/grassdata/test1/
grass /path/to/grassdata/test1/PERMANENT/ --exec r.external input=elevation.tiff output=elevation
grass /path/to/grassdata/test1/PERMANENT/ --exec r.univar map=elevation
```

The `--exec executable` syntax works for both single commands and executable scripts.

If you are scripting in Python (`#!/usr/bin/env python`), then you can use the above or, after a bootstrap to set `PYTHONPATH`, use *grass.script.setup.init* and (optionally) use the rest of the Python API ([link to documentation of grass.script.setup](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/libpython/grass.script.html#module-grass.script.setup)).

There is usually no need to set up the environment variables manually just to run the processing tools.